# NSpredicate one child item per parent

Tags: ios, swift, realm, nspredicate

I'm using Realm to store all the data in my app.

I have a shop item that contains a list of promotion ids and a promotion that have a parent property that is an id to the shop.

I now filter every promotion that is available now, and I like to add one more filter, so that the results list only contains one promotion per shop.

How can I complete the filter, so I only get one available promotion per shop?

Thanks!
// Kim

//EDIT

```
let startDate: Double = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970
let endDate: Double = currentDate.timeIntervalSince1970 

let parentPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "") 
let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "SUBQUERY(dates, $d, $d.start <= \(startDate) && $d.end >= \(endDate)).@count > 0")

self.realm?.objects(CSPromotions.self).filter(datePredicate).filter(parentPredicate)
```

Comment: You can you **AND** operator to concat more than one filter. `let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "color = %@ AND name BEGINSWITH %@", "tan", "B")`. Please follow the documentation https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#filtering

Comment: I'm aware of that, but how do I filter out all the promotions that have the same parent, so there is only one promotion per parent?

How do I write that predicate query ?

Comment: Can you share you code I mean what you have tried? Its tough to give you suggestion without the code.

Comment: I have added my code above. I haven't figured out how to solve it. 

So if I get all the promotions that is valid, the same shop can have 5 promotions in that result. I want to filter out 4 of them, so there is only one. 

I hop I can to it in the predicate because its faster than doing a filter on the list.

Comment: I think it should be like this if you wanna filter promotion based upon parent `let parentPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "parentid = %@ ",  relamobject.parentid)`

Comment: What is the `relamobject.parentid` referring to?
Because I don't have one shop but multiple shops, and the result should only contain one promotion per shop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm Swift [currently doesn't natively support distinct](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/1103), so there's no great way to do this. What you can do is manually build an array of the distinct values:

```
let shops = NSMutableSet()
let promotions = self.realm?.objects(CSPromotions.self).filter(datePredicate).filter(parentPredicate).filter {
    let id = $0.shop.id
    if shops.contains(id) {
        return false
    }
    shops.add(id)
    return true
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer ! :)